# Getting the cell clicked on in a TGridPanel

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, tgridpanel

I have a `TGridPanel` on a form and wish to add a control to a specific "cell" that is clicked on.

I can get the point easily enough:

```
procedure TForm1.GridPanel1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  P : TPoint;
  InsCol, InsRow : Integer;
begin
  P := (Sender as TGridPanel).ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
  if (Sender as TGridPanel).ControlAtPos(P) = nil then
    begin
      InsCol := ???;
      InsRow := ???;
      (Sender as TGridPanel).ControlCollection.AddControl(MyControl, InsCol, InsRow)
    end;
end;
```

I probably don't need the `if ControlAtPos(P) = nil then` line, but I want to make sure I'm not inserting a control in a cell that already has one in it.

So... what code do I use to get InsCol and InsRow?  I've been up and down the `TGridPanel` and `TControlCollection` class code and can't find anything that will give me a column or row value from mouse coordinates.  Nor does their seem to be a relevant event to use other than `OnDblClick()`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Changed variable Result to MyControl to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.GridPanel1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  P: TPoint;
  R: TRect;
  InsCol, InsRow : Integer;
begin
  P := (Sender as TGridPanel).ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos);
  for InsCol := 0 to GridPanel1.ColumnCollection.Count - 1 do
  begin
    for InsRow := 0 to GridPanel1.RowCollection.Count - 1 do
    begin
      R:= GridPanel1.CellRect[InsCol,InsRow];
      if PointInRect(P,R) then
      begin
        ShowMessage (Format('InsCol = %s and InsRow = %s.',[IntToStr(InsCol), IntToStr(InsRow)]))
      end;
    end;
  end;


end;

function TForm1.PointInRect(aPoint: TPoint; aRect: TRect): boolean;
begin
  begin
    Result:=(aPoint.X >= aRect.Left  ) and
            (aPoint.X <  aRect.Right ) and
            (aPoint.Y >= aRect.Top   ) and
            (aPoint.Y <  aRect.Bottom); 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I wish there was a more efficient way, but this does seem to be a reliable method.  By the way, Windows has an API called `PtInRect()` that does what your `PointInRect()` function does, but has the parameters in the reverse order.

Comment: Correction: The difference between your PointInRect() and Windows' PtInRect() is that the Windows version excludes the right and bottom edges.

Comment: I know that something exist like PointInRect. Because i ever seen it but i could not found it. Thanks Jerry to remind me of the function

Answer (score 0):

Here is an optimization of Ravaut123's approach (should be MUCH faster for larger grids).  This function will return the X/Y grid location in a TPoint.  If the user clicked on a valid column but not a valid row, then the valid column information is still returned, and the same goes for rows.  So it isn't "all or nothing" (valid cell or invalid cell).  This function assumes the grid is "regular" (every column has the same row height as the first column, likewise every row has the same column width as the first row).  If the grid is not regular then Ravaut123's solution is the better choice.

```
// APoint is a point in local coordinates for which you want to find the cell location.
function FindCellInGridPanel(AGridPanel: TGridPanel; const APoint: TPoint): TPoint;
var
  ICol, IRow : Integer;
  R : TRect;
begin
  Result.X := -1;
  Result.Y := -1;
  for ICol := 0 to AGridPanel.ColumnCollection.Count - 1 do
    begin
      R := AGridPanel.CellRect[ICol, 0];
      if (APoint.X >= R.Left) and (APoint.X <= R.Right) then
        begin
          Result.X := ICol;
          Break;
        end;
    end;
  for IRow := 0 to AGridPanel.RowCollection.Count - 1 do
    begin
      R := AGridPanel.CellRect[0, IRow];
      if (APoint.Y >= R.Top) and (APoint.Y <= R.Bottom) then
        begin
          Result.Y := IRow;
          Break;
        end;
    end;
end;
```